# using len() in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the look of my `DataFrame`:

```
   StateAb    GivenNm    Surname                  PartyNm PartyAb  ElectedOrder
35      WA        Joe    BULLOCK   Australian Labor Party     ALP             2
36      WA  Michaelia       CASH                  Liberal      LP             3
37      WA      Linda   REYNOLDS                  Liberal      LP             4
38      WA      Wayne  DROPULICH  Australian Sports Party    SPRT             5
39      WA      Scott     LUDLAM          The Greens (WA)     GRN             6
```

and I want to list a list of senators whose surname is more than 9 characters long.

So I think the code should be like this:

```
df[len(df.Surname) > 9]
```

but this raises a `KeyError`, where did I go wrong?

Comment: You can also do `df[df['Surname'].apply(len) > 9]` by the way which evaluates each string present in the series and returns `True` if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 22):

The correct way to filter a DataFrame based on the length of strings in a column is

```
df[df['Surname'].str.len() > 9]
```

`df['Surname'].str.len()` creates a Series of lengths for the surname column and `df[df['Surname'].str.len() > 9]` filters out the ones less than or equal to 9. What you did is to check the length of the Series itself (how many rows it has).

Comment: but if I want to output a list of senators whose elected order is 6, I can use df[df.ElectedOrder == 6], df.ElectedOrder is also a series, why len() is special?

Comment: `len(df)` returns the same result as `len(df['Surname'])` i.e. the number of rows. This is because `df['Surname']` is a `Series` (column object). You want to apply `len` to the strings in the column so you use `.str`

Comment: @ayhan So what does df['Surname'].str give? Is it a list?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the python [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter) function. It does exactly what you want.

```
df = [
    {"Surname": "Bullock-ish"},
    {"Surname": "Cash"},
    {"Surname": "Reynolds"},
]
longnames = list(filter(lambda s: len(s["Surname"]) > 9, df))
print(longnames)

>>[{'Surname': 'Bullock-ish'}]
```

Sytse